# Regularity of heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, estimation, heat-equation

I'm trying to find some references dealing with regularity and properties of the heat/Gaussian kernel
$$
G_t\left(x,y\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\, e^{-\left.\left(x-y\right)^2\right/2t}, \hspace{2ex} \text{for } \;x,y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
In particular, bounds on quantities like $\left\lvert\,\dfrac{\partial\hspace{0.1ex} G_t}{\partial \hspace{0.1ex}x}\,\left(\hspace{0.1ex}x,\hspace{0.2ex}y\hspace{0.1ex}\right)\,\right\rvert$, 
$\;\big\lvert\,G_t\hspace{0.1ex}\left(\hspace{0.1ex}x,\hspace{0.2ex}z\hspace{0.1ex}\right)-G_t\hspace{0.1ex}\left(\hspace{0.1ex}y,\hspace{0.2ex}z\hspace{0.1ex}\right)\hspace{0.05ex}\big\rvert$,
$\;\left\lvert\,\dfrac{\partial\hspace{0.1ex} G_t}{\partial \hspace{0.1ex}x}\,\left(\hspace{0.1ex}x,\hspace{0.2ex}z\hspace{0.1ex}\right) - \dfrac{\partial\hspace{0.1ex} G_t}{\partial \hspace{0.1ex}y}\,\left(\hspace{0.1ex}y,\hspace{0.2ex}z\hspace{0.1ex}\right)\,\right\rvert$, etc.

Do you know of any books, papers, or websites in which the author discusses and/or establishes various bounds on quantities like these?

Comment: Why have you used $z$ as an argument in the last two expressions?

Comment: Also, what types of bounds are you looking for? $\|\cdot\|_\infty$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb- Fix a real number $z$ (for example). I want to know how big/small I can make those quantities for $x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm not necessarily looking for bounds in that norm. I guess I'm mostly looking for nontrivial upper bounds for these kinds of quantities in the form of powers of the spatial variables ($x,y,z$), and powers of the time variable ($t$), times an exponential.  As an example, I want to know if I can bound the last quantity by something like $C |x-y|^a t^{-b}$ times an exponential term, for some constant $C$ and \emph{all} $a \in [0,1]$ and $b \in [1,3/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is long. You should study the book of L C Evans' PDE
[http://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0821849743](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743)
or took a graduate student level of the course on PDE.